# Solve git file conflict using SmartGit: ours vs theirs

Tags: git, smartgit, git-merge-conflict

I have a problem here and I don't know why, perhaps I did something wrong. I was working in the same file and other developer was working on it too. He told me that file was pushed to the repository, alright. Before pull the changes I made a commit so my changes was saved and merged with the ones from the other developer but surprise the file is giving me conflicts and I do not what to do for not to loose the other developer changes and mines too. If I open right click => Resolve conflict I got this window:

[image]

What each option there means? Which one is more secure and save both changes? (developer and mines)

If I open `Conflict solver` then I got something like this:

[image]

But again I don't know how or what to do in order to maintain both changes, any advice? Help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't use smartgit, but from the screenshot I can tell the options map to git commands as below:

1. do nothing, leave the file unresolved. not sure what will happen by choosing this option.
2. use other developers' changes as git command: `git checkout --ours -- FILE`
3. use my changes as git command: `git checkout --theirs -- FILE`
4. as you already did, open the conflict resolver.

You may be curious why we use `--theirs` when `using my changes`, while `--ours` when `using their changes`, this is because you are doing `rebase`, you are rebasing your original changes on other developers' changes. When you are doing `rebase`, it's like saving your changes in a temporary file, and moving the `HEAD` to the latest commit of the remote branch(other developers' changes), and replaying your changes over the current branch, in which case your changes become `theirs`.

Since you want to save both changes, you should resolve all the conflicts **manually**, and `mark the file as resolved` and then continue rebasing.

Comment: If you leave the file unresolved and then stage and commit, you commit a file with conflict markers in it.  Don't ask me how I found this out.  :-/